# What will be the complexity of this algorithm in the terms of n?

Tags: c++, while-loop, time-complexity

In the following algorithm the loop is increasing by the square of previous value of i,
what will be the complexity of this algorithm?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i=2;
    while(i<=n){
        cout<<"Something"<<endl;
        i=(i*i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @rustyx how would you please explain??

Comment: Why don't you try running it? You could estimate the complexity by just plotting for different values of `n`.

Comment: It's even more obvious if you output `i`.

Comment: it is increasing in power of 2 every time @MateenUlhaq

Comment: It is more obvious if you output log2(i) ;-)

Comment: Ah, so you claim that it outputs a sequence `2 4 8 16 32 ... 2^n`? I wonder what this suggests? There are `log2(n)` different numbers outputted.

Comment: I don't believe it produces that sequence.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq it doesn't produces that sequence. it produces 2 4 16 256 ..

Comment: it is actually log(log(n)) I think

Comment: That sounds about right

Comment: @kindacoder Trying to insult people will not make them like you more, and downvote less. Consider (re-)reading through [ask], and [help].

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius tell me what i have asked wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `log(log n)`

It goes like this:

```
a0 = 2
a1 = 2 * 2 = 4
a2 = 4 * 4 = 16
a3 = 16 * 16 = 256
...
```

In general terms this is:

```
ai = 2 ^ (2 ^ i)  where ^ is the power function
```

Now we solve

```
n = 2 ^ (2 ^ i)
```

for i which gives

```
i = log(log(n)/log(2))/log(2)
```

then replace the constants with 1 (i.e. log(2) -> 1) as we do with big O notation.

```
i ~ log(log(n))
```

So we need approx. log(log(n)) loops so we have

```
O(n) = log(log(n))
```